# Is there a way to create a datalist field in Flask WTForms?

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

Does anyone know of a way to create a `datalist` field using WTForms in Flask?

I know how to create a `SelectField` but I need to allow the user to enter their own value if it isn't in the list.

This is what I want to do http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp

Thanks

Comment: Probably related: [Security question & answer. What questions do you ask?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/44252/3906)

Comment: @MartinThoma How is a post about security questions relevant to creating a datalist field?

Comment: 2020 and still no reasonable way of doing some widget way to make SelectField renders options using `<datalist></datalist>` ?

Comment: at the moment I am too lazy to dig into it and pick [select2](https://select2.org/)

Comment: I have file an issue on WTForms on github https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/issues/653

Answer (score 16):

You create a simple StringField in your view.

```
autocomplete_input = StringField('autocomplete_input', validators=[DataRequired()])
```

In your template you call the field and add the list parameter (remember to pass the entries to your template):

```
{{form.autocomplete_input(list="id_datalist")}}
<datalist id="id_datalist">
{% for entry in entries %}
<option value={{ entry }}>
{% endfor %}
</datalist>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was easier to use JS library called [Select2](https://select2.org)

It connverts regular `<select>` tag into searchable interactive widget

Here is code from my template

```html
{% block content %}
{# Add styles and js libs #}
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-2Pmvv0kuTBOenSvLm6bvfBSSHrUJ+3A7x6P5Ebd07/g=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js" defer></script>

{# Old forms initialization here #}
{{super()}}

{# Activate Select2 #}
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#select-tag-id').select2();
    });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Also take a look at [docs with examples](https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage)