# How can I implement Bootstrap's Datalists with Flask-SQLAlchemy SelectField

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, flask, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

I am creating a form for my application. Currently, I want to take the user's gender, but I do not know how I can implement the field elegantly in my HTML.

I have been using Bootstrap for most of my HTML, so I want to carry that on and user their `Datalists` to display the various options.

Bootstrap's code for [`Datalists`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/form-control/#datalists) :

```
<label for="exampleDataList" class="form-label">Datalist example</label>
<input class="form-control" list="datalistOptions" id="exampleDataList" placeholder="Type to search...">
<datalist id="datalistOptions">
  <option value="San Francisco">
  <option value="New York">
  <option value="Seattle">
  <option value="Los Angeles">
  <option value="Chicago">
</datalist>
```

How I have been implementing forms, such as for the `StringField`:

```
<form method="post" novalidate>
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form.username.label }}
        {{ form.username(class_="form-control", size=32) }}
    </div>
  ...
```

How can I look to implement Flask-SQLAlchemy's [`SelectField`](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/fields/#wtforms.fields.SelectField) in a similar fashion?

*Note: I not too familiar with how Bootstrap fits with Jinja; the code I have written previously for forms is not very complicated, meaning I have not had to properly understand how it works - until now.*

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36283569/6843158) help ? The idea is to generate the HTML tags yourself instead of using WTF built-in methods. Or the alternative: extending WTForms [along these lines](https://gist.github.com/notquitehere/fba114b2495cfdd8ea52321074a310bd
)

Comment: Yeah, it helps, thanks. Not an ideal solution though, so it's still open if anyone can help.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question; but no answer.  After struggling for a while, I have got it to work.
forms.py:

```
    class fiscalYearForm(FlaskForm):
        fy_timeframe = SelectField(
            "Please Select Fiscal Quarter",
            choices=[
                ('FY2022 Q4', 'FY2022 Q4'),
                ('FY2022 Q3', 'FY2022 Q3'),
                ('FY2022 Q2', 'FY2022 Q2'),
                ('FY2022 Q1', 'FY2022 Q1'),
            ],
            validators=[DataRequired()],
        )
```

html file:

```
    <form action="" method="post">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        <div class="mb-3">
            {{ form.fy_timeframe.label(class="form-label") }}
            <input class="form-control" list="fylistOptions" placeholder="Type to search...">
            <datalist id="fylistOptions">
                    {{form.fy_timeframe(class="form-control form-control-sm")}}
            </datalist>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-primary" }}
        </div>
    </form>
```

This worked for me.  Hope it helps someone.